# How to properly update multiple records for SQLite/Phonegap

Tags: jquery, sqlite, cordova

I am writing a phonegap application. 
What I am trying to do is update multiple records at the same time. The code I posted below acts upon an order review screen. If the user updates the qty the table row gets the changed class added to it. Then when the user hits the update button the code below fires.

For our example, lets assume the user changed the qty of 3 line items. All 3 log correctly, and the transactions for all 3 log success. However, only the last of the 3 actually save to the database. What am I doing wrong here.

```
$('#update').click(function(){
    //update records where the tr has the changed class
    $('#log').append("<p>Update Clicked</p>");
    $('.changed').each(function(){
        order.Id=$(this).attr('id');
        item.qty=$(this).children().children().filter('#itemQTY').val();
        item.bercor=$(this).children().filter('#bercor').text();
        $('#log').append("<p>item.qty= " + item.qty + " and order.Id = " + order.Id + "item.bercor = " + item.bercor + " </p>" );
       //All three log correctly
        db.transaction(function(tx){
            tx.executeSql('update orderItems set qty=? where bercor=?',[item.qty,item.bercor],null,errorCB);
        },errorCB,successCB);
       //All three log success
    });
});
```

I can post more code if requested. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the transaction outside of the `each` like this:

```
$('#update').click(function(){
    //update records where the tr has the changed class
    $('#log').append("<p>Update Clicked</p>");
    db.transaction(function(tx){
        $('.changed').each(function(){
            order.Id=$(this).attr('id');
            item.qty=$(this).children().children().filter('#itemQTY').val();
            item.bercor=$(this).children().filter('#bercor').text();
            $('#log').append("<p>item.qty= " + item.qty + " and order.Id = " + order.Id + "item.bercor = " + item.bercor + " </p>" );
            //All three log correctly
                tx.executeSql('update orderItems set qty=? where bercor=?',[item.qty,item.bercor],null,errorCB);
            //All three log success
        });
    },errorCB,successCB);
});
```